# Console.Read() not work correctly

Tags: c#, insert

```
        int y = 0; 
        Console.WriteLine("insert x");
        int x = Console.Read();
        Console.WriteLine("insert n");
        int n = Console.Read();
        Console.WriteLine("insert a");
        int a = Console.Read();
        int sum  = (2 * n - 1) * a;
        int sum2 = (2 * n * a);
        int sum3 = (2 * n + 1) * a;
        if (x <= 0) y = 0;
        else if (x > sum && x <= sum2) y = a;
        else if (x > sum2 && x <= sum3 || n <= 3 || n >= 1) y = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Y = " + y);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

can't insert all values. after i insert x  y printed and console close, what is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ReadLine and convert to int 32

Thes is the right code:

```
        int y = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("insert x");
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("insert n");
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("insert a");
        int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int sum = (2 * n - 1) * a;
        int sum2 = (2 * n * a);
        int sum3 = (2 * n + 1) * a;
        if (x <= 0) y = 0;
        else if (x > sum && x <= sum2) y = a;
        else if (x > sum2 && x <= sum3 || n <= 3 || n >= 1) y = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Y = " + y);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `Read` use `ReadLine`. Only then you can be sure the user actually pressed `ENTER` and the **entire line** is returned - `Read` blocks until the user presses `ENTER`, but then returns the ASCII code of only **one character**. If you read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) example, this becomes clear.

In your example, if you enter "1" and press `ENTER`, the next calls to `Read` will actually return the ASCII codes for `1`, `\r` and `\n`.

To be clear: `Read` does **not** return the entered *number*, but the *ASCII code* of the character you entered, so you're using it wrong - what you need to do is convert the string the user enters to a number like so:

```
int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

You could also check for errors easily like this:

```
int number;
if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
{
    Console.WriteLine("What you entered is not a number!");
    return;
}
```

Comment: when i use ReadLine i get error cuz i cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Comment: Yes. Of course you do, and you should. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Console.Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) reads only the **next character**. This is not what you want. What happens is this:

- you type `7` => you read the character (ascii code) `0x37` for `x`
- you press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> => you read `0x0A` (`\r`) for `n`
  etc...

you want to use `Console.ReadLine()` which terminates when you hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and returns a `string` that you can parse as `int`:

```
Console.Write("Insert x: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int x = int.Parse(input);
```

You may want to add error handling if the user types "abc" instead of an `int` or use

```
int x;
if (!int.TryParse(input, out x))
    Console.WriteLine("This was no number!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone has given a solution but the reason why
Your code doesn't work is this.

The 
    Console.Read

Returns the ASCII value of the keypressed. 
It means saying something like

```
int i = Console.Read();
```

And hitting the 4key on your keyboard will store the value 53, which is the ASCII value of the 4key in variable i instead of ur intended integer "4".

To fully understand this check variable values by using breakpoints after Console.Read to see what is really stored in variable a, n and y.